# How to increase the limit for downloading data from Firebase when scrolling?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to list items,and first,i want to load 20 items,then when i scroll to limit,I want download the next 20 data,and so on...if anyone could tell me the simplest way to do that?
 thank you !

Comment: you can make a custom recycle adapter extending from Firebase recycler adapter.

Comment: so it cant be done with firebaserecycleradapter,i must make custom adapter?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e You will need a functionality in semblance with this.